# getting garbage value when I add variable with value in c while finding number of digit and printing reverse of a number

Tags: c

I am writing a program to count number of digit and reverse the number but the garbage value is getting printed when assign value to datatype while declaring

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
    int n=213,t=0,a,e,i=0;
    e=n;
    while(e!=0)
    { 
        e/=10;
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d",i);

    while(n!=0){
        t=n%10;
        a=a*10+t;
        n/=10;
    }
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the variable `a` with zero, before doing this

```
a=a*10+t; /* a contains garbage data here, initialize it before */
```

else `a` default contains *garbage value* due to its **automatic storage**. 
For e.g

```
int n=213,t=0,a = 0 /* initialize a with 0 */,e,i=0;
```